# User roles by Taxonomy term - webservice

Tags: taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

I am very newbie to Drupal (I know how to write code in Java way) but this task has Java and PHP in one solution. So, I need to write some webservice to manage the taxonomy terms by user roles. I mean I have one vocabulary for each user role and in GUI way I can easily click some terms and update those dependencies (publish term for role). But in webservice way it is more complicated for me now. I have the Taxonomy Access Control Lite module and my question is: what is the easiest way to do it? Is there some function in Drupal 7 to do that? And how does taxonomy term is connected with user roles in standard Drupal 7 DB? I will be happy to have any advice from you guys. Thanks in advance.